# How to compute system.time in micro seconds?

Tags: r, performance

Is there a way to change the precision of system.time?

```
system.time(sum(seq(1.0,10^4,1)))
```

To something like:

```
round(system.time(sum(seq(1.0,10^4,1))),digits=6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the package `microbenchmark` for this purpose.

From the package `DESCRIPTION`:

```
Package:            microbenchmark
Title:              Sub microsecond accurate timing functions.
Description:        Provides infrastructure to accurately measure and compare the execution time of R expressions.
```